# c++ pointer/array distinction

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am practicing for a c++ midterm, and I can't see why the following code is incorrect.

```
int ip[] = {6, 7, 2, 4, -5};
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i, ++ip)
    cout << *ip;
```

My suspicion is that is it something to do with the -5, but I'm lost, and I'd really like to get this resolved.

Comment: an array variable is equivalent to a constant pointer. So it can't be incremented or modified in any way.

Comment: @Pramod No, an array variable is *not* equivalent to a constant pointer. For example, `sizeof(array)` is generally not the same as `sizeof(pointer)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot increase `ip`, since it is an array, and not a pointer - so its value [`ip`] is fixed.

So, the problem is with the expression `++ip`

Comment: They are not, arrays have special semantics. You can also check what is the value of `&ip` [the answer is `&ip == ip`], which is not true for pointers.

Comment: @Zack: That's a common misconception. It would be better to say that a pointer value can be produced from any array and that pointers can be used to simulate arrays using pointer arithmetic (so they certainly *look* very similar). But for the language itself, pointers and arrays very much distinct entities.

Comment: While I am at it, int* ip = (int*)20;
++ip;


this code would end with 24 for ip, correct? Because integer pointer increment by 4 bytes each time?

Comment: You're probably also confused by the fact that arrays decay into pointers in C and C++, but they are not precisely the same thing. If you take that for loop that is currently giving you a syntax error and move it inside a function that looks like void print_array(int ip[], int n), it will actually work fine because passing the array into a function cause the array to decay to a pointer that can be incremented.

Comment: @Zack Yes and no.  `ip` can never have the value 24, because 24 is an integer value, and pointers aren't integers.  But incrementing an `int*` does cause it to point to the next element of the `int[]`, providing the `int*` points into an `int[]`.  (Whether `int` is four bytes is another question: I'm aware of systems where it is six bytes, and I've worked a lot on systems where it was only 2 bytes.)

Comment: @amit: `&ip == ip` is a type error, because `int(*)[5]` and `int*` are different types.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you can't increment the value of a static pointer, aka an array.

The easy solution is to simply use the indexing operator `[]`.

```
int ip[] = {6, 7, 2, 4, -5};
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    cout << ip[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access these elements directly by using index:

```
int ip[] = {6, 7, 2, 4, -5};
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    cout << ip[i];
```

or if you want to use pointer arithmetic for this purpose, you could use temporary variable - pointer that will point to first element of this array:

```
int ip[] = {6, 7, 2, 4, -5};
int* myPtr = ip;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i, ++myPtr)
    cout << *myPtr;
```

Note that `int* myPtr = ip;` is equal to `int* myPtr = &ip[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is:

1. when it comes to an array `ip[]`,ip is pointing to the first element
   of array and it is fixed and it cannot be changed(it is like a
   constant pointer i.e pointing to a fixed memory location.)

   2.so when you are incrementing it you are violating the condition that's why you are getting an error

try this instead

```
int ip[] = {6, 7, 2, 4, -5};
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    cout << ip[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

`ip` is a static array.. you cannot increase it!
eventually you can create another pointer that points to `ip`:

```
int* p = ip;
```

then increment `p`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to increase each value of the array ip[] separately

Answer (score 0):

Pointers and arrays are distinct things.
Pointers decay to arrays, but it doesn't work the other way around.
The operator++ is not defined on arrays, so ip decays to a pointer, the pointer (unnamed temporary) is incremented, but you can't store it back into ip, because ip is an array.

The code below should work, as you expect.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
        int ip[] = {6, 7, 2, 4, -5};
        int *p=ip;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i, ++p)
            std::cout << *p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to formalize somewhat what others are saying: `ip` is an array, not
a pointer.  It converts implicitly to a pointer, but the results of an
implicit conversion are an rvalue, and the `++` operator requires an
lvalue.  Other than the implicit conversion (which doesn't occur in all
contexts), there is no real relationship between arrays and pointers.

Note too that in C++, `[]` is not defined for array types, only for
pointers (or for types with user defined overloads).  It only works with
arrays because of the implicit conversion.